# Activating particular LineEdit while taking input from on screen numpad

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qlineedit

I am making a login form in qt where input is taken from the numpad. The numpad is created on screen. When I am trying to take input from the numpad, 
It takes the input in the both of the lineEdit field. So how can I separate both of these while taking the input from the numpad?

```
  #include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "mainscreen.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->dB1,SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(display()));
    connect(ui->dB2,SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(display()));
    connect(ui->dB3,SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(display()));
    connect(ui->dB4,SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(display()));
    connect(ui->dB5,SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(display()));
    connect(ui->dB6,SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(display()));
    connect(ui->dB7,SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(display()));
    connect(ui->dB8,SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(display()));
    connect(ui->dB9,SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(display()));
    connect(ui->dB0,SIGNAL(released()),this,SLOT(display()));


}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::display()
{
    QPushButton *qp=(QPushButton*)sender();
      ui->lineEdit->setText(ui->lineEdit->text()+qp->text());
      ui->lineEdit_2->setText(ui->lineEdit_2->text()+qp->text());
}


void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString username=ui->lineEdit->text();
    QString password=ui->lineEdit_2->text();

    if(username=="text"&&password=="text")
    {
     hide();
     main_scn=new MainScreen();
     main_scn->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window|Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
     main_scn->show();

    }
}
```

the UI is here, please check this out

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a numpad in that way is inconvenient since it will place the text in both QLineEdit, and usually the username and password are not always the same.

My proposal is to create a Numpad that does not need to be connected by signals, but an event will be sent so that the widget that has the focus.

**numpadwidget.h**

```
#ifndef NUMPADWIDGET_H
#define NUMPADWIDGET_H

#include <QApplication>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QToolButton>
#include <QWidget>

class NumpadWidget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit NumpadWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent)
    {
        QGridLayout *lay = new QGridLayout(this);

        const std::vector<QPair<QString, int>> values{{"1", Qt::Key_1}, {"2", Qt::Key_2}, {"3", Qt::Key_3},
                                                      {"4", Qt::Key_4}, {"5", Qt::Key_5}, {"6", Qt::Key_6},
                                                      {"7", Qt::Key_7}, {"8", Qt::Key_8}, {"9", Qt::Key_9},
                                                      {".", Qt::Key_Colon}, {"0", Qt::Key_0}, {"*", Qt::Key_Asterisk}};

        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;

        for(const QPair<QString, int> & value : values){
            QToolButton *button =new QToolButton;
            button->setText(value.first);
            button->setFixedSize(40,40);
            lay->addWidget(button, i, j);
            button->setProperty("text", value.first);
            button->setProperty("key", value.second);
            connect(button, &QToolButton::clicked, this, &NumpadWidget::onClicked);
            j++;
            if(j % 3 == 0){
                j=0;
                i++;
            }
        }
        setFixedSize(sizeHint());
    }
private slots:
    void onClicked()
    {
        if(QWidget *widget = QApplication::focusWidget()){
            QString text = sender()->property("text").toString();
            int key = sender()->property("key").toInt();
            QKeyEvent * event = new QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, key, Qt::NoModifier, text);
            QCoreApplication::postEvent(widget, event);
        }
    }
};

#endif // NUMPADWIDGET_H
```

Then the NumpadWidget is promoted so that it can be used in Qt Designer, in the following [link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html#promoting-widgets) it indicates how to do it

The complete project can be found in the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/51490722).

Comment: Why didn't you use QVector instead of vector?

Comment: @k111 Anyone should work, I have a habit of using std::XXX, did my answer work?

Comment: @k111 If my answer helps you, do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it, check the [tour], that's the best way to thank. ;)

Comment: How can I see the value of sizeHint()?

Comment: @k111 I do not understand you, explain yourself.

Comment: What is the purpose of using the sizeHint()?

Comment: @k111 
When you use a layout it has a minimum size but when you expand it will also try to occupy everything is possible space so in this example will cause the buttons to separate and that is the effect that I do not want. Recommendation: comment that line and understand why I put it. :)

Comment: I comment out the sizeProperty(). Is it any kind of error I'll get in the future?

Comment: @k111 What sizeProperty()?

Comment: ` button->setProperty("text", value.first);
  button->setProperty("key", value.second); `

Comment: some keys have text information, but others do not, for example the CTRL key, does not have associated text but a key so my solution gives a general perspective of how a QKeyEvent should be created, I do not know if you will have problems in the future but removing it does not make sense, why do you want to remove it?

Comment: @k111 explain line by line is not the idea of ​​comments, please first read the documentation, modify, experiment, understand and when you have a real doubt just make me arrive, the time of others is valuable.

Comment: No I just wanted to know, what is the role of it in the code. :)

Comment: @k111 
As I emphasize read the documentation, I am not your teacher, I publish an answer and I hope that you read, investigate, modify, etc, and then when you have a specific question that may not be well documented, you ask me a question. Explanation line by line is not the idea, can you imagine how much time I would invest if you ask me for each line of all my answers ?, a longer time to the time I invested in helping you.

Comment: Sorry for that. Remember this further.